# How to prevent multiple spam chat sessions from a user in LiveAgent?

Tags: liveagent

Is there any way to prevent a user from opening multiple chat sessions in LiveAgent. I know there is **"X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY"** header in SessionId response. **"X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY"** system-generated ID used to identify the Live Agent session on the Live Agent servers. But can the multiple sessions be prevented from code/config.

The user is changing Ip frequently so Ip based blocking will not work. I would love to hear your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use a pre-chat form? If so, you could implement a honey-pot or a captcha in the form to prevent spam bots.

Comment: @PepeFloyd yes we do use pre-chat form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a pre-chat form and all you want to do is to prevent spam bots, you could simply add a captcha or a honeypot validation to the form. This way, only real users would get through the form.